# How to make ActiveMQ transportConnector property environmentaly-dependent

Tags: jboss, port, activemq-classic

I'm looking for a way to replace this on my ActiveMQ config:

```
   <transportConnector uri="tcp://localhost:60019"> disableAsyncDispatch="false"/>
```

with a "`not-hardcoded`" URI (e.g., replacing "`localhost`" with a variable that resolves to an instance dependent value). The problem is that as we have many `JBoss` instances per server, and that URI above resolves to `0.0.0.0:60019`, only one instance at a time can be running, unless we configure it in a per-application basis, which is not only frustrating, but there are circumstances where it is not enough (should be per-instance based, which is much more frustrating).

Each `JBoss` server has its own IP address, so I thought of using `${jboss.bind.address}` to circumvent this, but it won't syntax. We also have an environment variable `%SERVERIP%` which could be used for this calling it from a start up script, but I don't know if `ActiveMQ` reads an environment variable for assigning its transport connector URI.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-placeholderconfigurer) and you should be able to replace the uri with some ${variable} from file or from jvm system variable. This should work since ActiveMQ configuration is really just a Spring context.